# I want to store the changes made in a table the application in a new table in Spring using EntityManager

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

There is a table inventory and i want to store changes made in it into a new table log.
I have created a model for log.

```
@Component
public class MasterInventoryListener {

    @PersistenceContext
    private static EntityManager entityManager;

    public MasterInventoryListener(final EntityManager entityManager) {
        MasterInventoryListener.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    @Transactional
    public void preUpdate(MasterInventory masterInventory) {
        MasterInventory oldState = entityManager.find(MasterInventory.class, masterInventory.getId());

        Map<String, Object> objectMap = ObjectMapperUtils.toObjectMap(oldState, false);
        Map<String, Object> newObjectMap = ObjectMapperUtils.toObjectMap(masterInventory, false);
        InventoryAuditLog log = new InventoryAuditLog();
        log.setSellerId(masterInventory.getSellerId());
        log.setOldState(ObjectMapperUtils.toJsonString(oldState, false));
        log.setNewState(ObjectMapperUtils.toJsonString(masterInventory, false));
        entityManager.persist(log);
    }
}
```

But here i am getting EntityManager is null.
I have been suggested some way to add this in

```
  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void loadSecurityContextForNonWebApplication() {
    if (AppConfiguration.isNonWebApplication()) {
      UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository
        .findByEmail("dapl.bot@darshita.in").orElse(null);
      if (Objects.nonNull(userProfile)) {
        roleToProfileMap.put(Role.SYSTEM, userProfile);
        log.info("Security context loaded for non-web application with user: {}",
          userProfile.getEmail());
      } else {
        log.warn("Security context not loaded for non-web application, user not found");
      }
    } else {
      userProfileRepository.findByEmail("anonymous@darshita.in")
        .ifPresent((userProfile) -> roleToProfileMap.put(Role.ANONYMOUS, userProfile));
    }
  }
```

using class SessionContextHolder which holds detail of the session class. Suggest some way to keep the entity manager to keep this entity

Comment: You would run into updates on updates on updates with this. Use something like Hibernate Envers or Javers to write the changes instead of rolling your own.

Comment: i saw those and seem perfect for this use case but i have been instructed to solve in this manner only. The only problem is that there is no bean for MasterInventoryListener class and thus EntityManager is getting null. Just want some way to get EntityManager

Comment: It was solved by getting the current state by using JDBCTemplate and updating it via EntityManager in the log table.